# how to set delegate and display into console (C#)?

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm resolving C# delegate question and I'm stuck in this part please help me out.
I want to display code fragments together win the method callMe, and the integer 3 should be displayed in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you call a delegate `MyClass`? That's confusing. It's not a class, it's a *delegate*, something like a method reference. Well, anyway...

IMHO that definition is wrong. Currently the code is

```
public delegate void MyClass(int numOfWords);
```

which says: I have a method that returns `void` (nothing) and accepts an `int`. You don't have such a method. Instead the method you have returns an `int` and accepts a `StringBuilder`. The declaration should look like:

```
public delegate int MyClass(StringBuilder sb);
```

You can now simply call the delegate (because it points to a method). There's no need to define another method.

```
Console.WriteLine(k(stb));
```